# No hillshade effect when no-data area is on screen

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, hillshade

I'm facing this weird problem when hillshade effect partially brakes if a no-data area appears on screen.
If I move the area to hide it off screen, the hillshade effect works.
I tried changing symbology, colors,classes etc without change.

[image: Hillshade broken]

[image: Hillshade]

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you open a brand new MXD and import the data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean doing it all from scratch just in case it works?
I did that already, no luck.

I also saved it and reopened many times.

Comment: @Martin suggested to open a new (blank) mxd, load only the hillshade layer (alone with no other layers) and see what happens. The problem could be the mxd file, not the hillshade itself. give it a try.

Comment: I have to clarify that I started using Arcmap some months ago, so I'm still a noob, apologies if I don't get it straight away or if I don't make sense.

In this case, you mean creating a blank map like one in the screenshot?

https://s13.postimg.org/m30vlkss7/Untitled.png

In this case, how can I save only the hillshade layer to import it after?
I just ticked the hillshade effect and I'm saving my whole work as an .mxd file. That contains the raster of the area I'm working on.

https://s14.postimg.org/3m1an4jw1/Untitled2.png


Is there a way to save the hillshade and only that?

Comment: Ah, that should explain things. Use the [Hillshade function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/hillshade-function.htm) instead, and apply some transparency for visual effect. The on-the-fly hillshade function has some issues, in my experience.

Comment: Perfect, that worked.
Now, one last problem as a result of the function.
The effect is much more"analog", with less detail compared to the "on the fly" hillshade effect.
You can see for your self here and compare to the picture above:

https://s16.postimg.org/ek2qjh24l/Untitled.png

Any ideas for this last obstacle?

Comment: Good! You can try to play around with the parameters, primarily Z factor but also azimuth and altitude and see if you get different results. Read on my previous link for more info on what they do.